# connect to memsql from pyspark shell

Tags: pyspark, singlestore

Is it possible to connect to memsql from pyspark?

I heard that memsql recently built the streamliner infrastructure on top of pyspark to allow for custom python transformation

But does this mean I can run pyspark or submit a python spark job that connects to memsql?

Comment: Are you referring to this tool: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/spark/memsql-spark-interface-python/? Or more generically? This is definitely possible in both contexts.

Comment: No, I'm talking about pyspark shell, for example I want to run "memsql-ops pyspark"

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both questions.

Streamliner is the best approach if your aim is to get data into MemSQL or perform transformation during ingest. How to use Python with Streamliner: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/spark/memsql-spark-interface-python/

You can also query MemSQL from a Spark application. Details on that here: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/spark/spark-sql-pushdown/

You can also run a Spark shell. See http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ops/cli/SPARK-SHELL/ & http://docs.memsql.com/latest/spark/admin/#launching-the-spark-shell

Comment: None of the links talk about running the pyspark shell. what I want is to run the pyspark shell not scala spark-shell. If this is not possible, then how can I create a python spark job and submit it using spark-submit?

Comment: You can find pyspark and spark-submit in `/var/lib/memsql-ops/data/spark/install/bin` when you deploy Spark using MemSQL-Ops.

Comment: What is the command to run pyspark with the support of memsql-spark connector? In scala shell you see msc (memsql spark context)  object created and ready to interact with memsql, but you don't find this when you start pyspark

Comment: There is not one that can be launched with the `memsql-ops` tool currently, as you have surmised from the documentation.